# Vee Validate: SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I use VeeValidate and regex for password with requirement: At least two characters from uppercase, lowercase, numbers, and symbols.

```
v-validate="required|min:8|max:20|regex:/^(?=(.*?[a-z].*?[A-Z])|(.*?[a-z].*?[0-9])|(.*?[a-z].*?[!@#$%^&*()_+])|(.*?[A-Z].*?[0-9])|(.*?[A-Z].*?[!@#$%^&*()_+])|(.*?[0-9].*?[!@#$%^&*()_+])).*$/"
```

But the browser displays an error message:

> [Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "value": "SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: 
>   //^(?=(.*?[a-z].*?[A-Z])/: Unterminated group"

Thanks for support.

[Error stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqXN1.png)

Answer (score 1):

We should use the object format of the rules instead.

> Heads up!
>
> You should not use the pipe '|' or commas ',' within your regular
>   expression when using the string rules format as it will cause a
>   conflict with how validators parsing works. You should use the object
>   format of the rules instead.

```
v-validate="{required: true, min:8, max:20,
regex:/^(?=(.*?[a-z].*?[A-Z])|(.*?[a-z].*?[0-9])|(.*?[a-z].*?[!@#$%^&*()_+])|(.*?[A-Z].*?[0-9])|(.*?[A-Z].*?[!@#$%^&*()_+])|(.*?[0-9].*?[!@#$%^&*()_+]))/}"
```

**Update the latest regex**:  At least two characters from uppercase, lowercase, numbers, and symbols.

```
v-validate="{required: true, min:8, max:20,
regex:/^(?=(.*?[a-z].*?[A-Z])|(.*?[A-Z].*?[a-z])|(.*?[a-z].*?[0-9])|(.*?[0-9].*?[a-z])|(.*?[a-z].*?[!@#$%^&*()_+])|(.*?[!@#$%^&*()_+].*?[a-z])|(.*?[A-Z].*?[0-9])|(.*?[0-9].*?[A-Z])|(.*?[A-Z].*?[!@#$%^&*()_+])|(.*?[!@#$%^&*()_+].*?[A-Z])|(.*?[0-9].*?[!@#$%^&*()_+])|(.*?[!@#$%^&*().*?[0-9]_+])).*$/}"
```